# How to change front page template based on url alias?

Tags: 7, theming

I have many homepages and template file for every homepage and also a custom template for the front page the problem is when I change the default front page in admin/config/system/site-information to any other alias the page still have the page--front.tpl.php styles not the custom node style page--node--68.tpl.php , any help please ?

Comment: Have you tried to clear your theme cache? you need to clear the theme cache before they will be active.

Comment: @iamroald : yes I cleared the cache, the problem is the url alias became the front page so it reads the front page template not it's own original template .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 7, template suggestions are added/modified in the preprocess function, in this case `HOOK_preprocess_page()`.

Add this to the template.php file in your theme root directory; you may need to create this file.

The problem is that the page--node--id suggestion is *weaker* than page--front and does not get used. We need to move the page--node--id suggestion to the end of the `theme_hook_suggestions` array, so it overrides page--front.

Add this snippet. I have added comments to explain what each line of code does. Replace *ThemeName* with your theme name.

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page template.
 */
function ThemeName_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // Check if this is the front page and a node is the front page.
  if ($variables['is_front'] == TRUE && isset($variables['node'])) {

    // Foreach over the theme_hook_suggestions array.
    foreach ($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] as $key => $value) {

      // Does the suggestion match the current node?
      if ($value == 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->nid) {

        // Match, unset the template suggestion.
        unset($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][$key]);

        // Push the template suggestion onto the end of the array, this will give
        // it precedence over page--front.
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->nid;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think this is the easiest/quickest way to *move* an array item to the end, where it will override page--front.

Comment: This is brilliant it worked like a charm thank you so much :D

Comment: You're welcome, and again, sorry for the noise of the first answer, however I'm sure it will help someone some day :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work on you this will allow you define/add your custom tpl base on url alias,

Example: you have url alias /sample then your custom tpl should be page--sample.tpl.php
if you dump the variables variable in theme_preprocess_page you will notice that there's a new tpl suggested in theme_hook_suggestions 'page__sample' you jus need to create a new tpl in templates directory name it page--sample.tpl.php

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page().
 */
function exmaple_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (module_exists('path')) {
    $url_alias = drupal_get_path_alias(str_replace('/edit', '', $_GET['q']));
    foreach(explode('/', $url_alias) as $path_part) {
      $template = 'page__' . $path_part;
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $template;
    }
  }
}
```